# Unable to run PowerShell file as task in release pipeline - permission error

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script file as a task in the release pipeline. I tried a simple instruction like `Write-Output "Hello World"` and the script failed with the message

> AuthorizationManager check failed. CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

If I run an inline script inside a PowerShell task it works perfectly.

So, my question is: what should be my user role in Visual Studio Team Services for running PowerShell scripts files?

This is how the script is setup
[image]

Comment: are you running in a dedicated or hosted agent?

Comment: Is visual Studio online, so I think is the vsts agent

Comment: what if you test the same thing with write-host instead?

Comment: The problema is not the instruction, if i put online script IT works, the problem is executing the script from a file, si basically i Need to know what kind of toke do I Need in vsts to be Able to Execute a script in a file

Comment: You should not need any particular right as long as your script is on source control and that the agent is getting it as part of build process.

Comment: I'm guessing I do need some kind of permision (I'm not the global administrator of the project) because if a run an inline powershell script it works, but if I run a simple script like write-host "Hello" from a powershell file it says I have a security problem.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot on how the script task is configured please?

Comment: Image is now part of the question

Comment: thanks, this looks properly configured to me. Just to make sure, can you also provide a screenshot of the agent section when you queue the build?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was trying to run the script from a share drive. Now I copied the files locally to the agent and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it seems that the problem was the trusting of the powershell. In more detail as this powershell was created from a file that belonged to a git repo and edited on another computer, then it was not trusted on the computer that I wanted to execute.

Right click on the powershell and check **unblock**. This resolved the issue for me running this powershell script through Azure Devops.

[image]